# List comprehension of a specific form

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

How to create such a list comprehension that given

```
[(i,j) | i <- [1..4], j <- [1..4]] yields the following:

[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(3,3),(4,3),(4,4)]
```

i.e. listing all the combinations with respect to j?

PS. Swapping the places of "i" and "j" isn't the solution I am looking for.

Comment: Hey you've asked several questions now but haven't accepted any answers. If someone has answered your question, check the green check-mark beside their answer. It marks the question as "answered" and gives them reputation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since in your desired output the first component is always at least as large as the second, let `i` start from `j`, instead of from 1:

```
[(i,j) | j <- [1 .. 4], i <- [j .. 4]]
```

With the `j <- [1 .. 4]` generator first, the `j` is in scope and can be used for the `i` generator.

Comment: Curses, 10 seconds too slow.

Comment: @Xymostech Usually, that's my line. I know your pain.

Comment: Tyvm, but what if I had words instead of numbers in the example?

Comment: @Warditive What setting? Have you a list of words, and want pairs of two words from the list, the first component coming not before the second in the list, or what?

Comment: I would like something following this pattern: [Two .. Four] [Pears .. Oranges] - i.e. listing all the possible combinations with "Pears" and afterwards listing those with "Oranges". Example: "Two Pears, Three Pears, Four Pears, Two Oranges, Three Oranges, Four Oranges". :)

Comment: @Warditive `[(count, fruit) | fruit <- [Pears .. Oranges], count <- [Two .. Four]]`. If you want to have `[(Two,Pears),(Three,Pears),(Four,Pears),(Three,Oranges),(Four,Oranges)]`, i.e. the count depend on the fruit, you need a function to compute start and endpoint of the count range from the fruit.

Comment: That's exactly the function I need. How to create a similar one in Haskell?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26792/discussion-between-warditive-and-daniel-fischer)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a boolean guard:

```
[(i,j) | i <- [1..4], j <- [1..4], i >= j]
```